# Placing Arrows Next To Terms

Tags: javascript, php, html

I'm using a snippet of PHP to place arrows next to previous and next terms. So when a user is on a page, they can click the anchor arrow to jump to the next section.

**The general output of the code should be:**

(arrow) Previous Section             Next Section (arrow)

Right now, I am having trouble properly placing the arrow for the Next Section on the right side of the proper term.

**Here is the code snippet of the lines I'm struggling with:**

```
'<div class="section-prev"><a href="#' . preg_replace('/\W+/','',strtolower(strip_tags($previous_section->name))) . '">&uparrow; ' . $previous_section->name . '</a></div>'; 

'<div class="section-next"><a href="#' . preg_replace('/\W+/','',strtolower(strip_tags($next_section->name))) . '">&downarrow; ' . $next_section->name . '</a></div>';
```

They are currently both set to have the arrow on the left side of the word, but I need the "section-next" class to have the arrow on the right.

**Thanks!**

Comment: It's be easier to read and better performance to set `preg_replace('/\W+/','',strtolower(strip_tags($previous_section->name)))` to a variable, running less functions leads to faster generation.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to move the arrow to the right side of the anchor text.

```
'<div class="section-prev"><a href="#' . preg_replace('/\W+/','',strtolower(strip_tags($previous_section->name))) . '">&uparrow; ' . $previous_section->name . '</a></div>'; 

'<div class="section-next"><a href="#' . preg_replace('/\W+/','',strtolower(strip_tags($next_section->name))) . '">' . $next_section->name . ' &downarrow;</a></div>';
```